# Why does update in multiple locations act like SET instead of UPDATE?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

SETUP

At `/demo/key` is a value like `{a:1, b:2, c:3}`

At `/user/demo/key` there is a value like `true`

```
var database = firebase.database();
var rootRef = database.ref();
```

Scenario A

```
rootRef.child('demo/key').update({a:0});
// Result -> {a:0, b:2, c:3}
// b and c not overwritten, still exist -> happy
// update() acts like I expected / read
```

Scenario B

```
var data = {a:7};
var updates = {};
    updates[`/demo/${key}`] = data;
    updates[`/user/demo/${key}`] = true;

rootRef.update(updates);
// Result -> {a:7}
// b:2, c:3 are gone -> Acts like set() ???
// Expected -> {a:7, b:2, c:3}
```

I'm not sure why this is... but I would have expected that the `update()` function would act the same way in either instance and do a partial write.

Am I doing something wrong or missing a key concept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does work like `update`. When you pass data to `update`, each key is `set` and the keys' siblings that are not included in the data are left untouched.

All you need to do to ensure that `b` and `c` are not removed is to use a more specific key. For example:

```
var updates = {};
    updates[`/demo/${key}/a`] = 7;
    updates[`/user/demo/${key}`] = true;
```

Comment: Hm. I see what you're saying. I guess my thinking was that the data properties would be reflected as the more specific keys. What I could do is take `data = {a:7}` and dynamically generate the more specific update references so as not to overwrite. Is this what people do?

Comment: Yep, that's what I would do.